# Existe a possibilidade de perda de dados durante a conversão de tipos de dados text para nvarchar(max)?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um banco de dados legado em produção com dados armazenados com o tipo `text` porém houve a necessidade de converte-los para nvarchar(max) e por acaso [eu vi](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que esta já era uma recomendação da Microsoft devido à questão do tipo `text` estar preterido.

A dúvida é se uma conversão direta entre os tipo seria uma melhor opção, visto que não está claro se existe algum problema neste processo, como por exemplo diferenças incompatibilidade de encoding ou perda de dados ?

Obrigado

Comment: poderia postar o código?

Comment: Não sou DBA, então por favor não se assuste com minha abordagem, mas seria uma alteração direta de um tipo de campo para outro, algo como :

`ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN c NVARCHAR (MAX);`

Comment: Precisa ser nvarchar? Não pode ser somente varchar? Atento que o tipo de dados nvarchar ocupa o dobro de espaço.

Answer (score 1):

Se a versão do teu banco de dados for menor que SQL Server 2019, use `NVARCHAR(max)` para minimizar problemas de conversão.  A implementação básica de ambos os tipos `TEXT` e `VARCHAR(max)` é praticamente a mesma mas com `NVARCHAR(max)` você um tipo de dados grande o suficiente para suportar essa mudança.

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <column_name> NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Isso transformará sua coluna `TEXT` em uma coluna `NVARCHAR(max)` sem qualquer perda de dados.